# Setting custom LCL and UCL limits with qcc (Rstudio)

Tags: r, intervals, qcc

Perhaps this is an easy question but I am quite new wirh R and am struggling to define custom UCL and LCL limits in xBar control charts. In productions we have already set tollerances that must be fulfilled and I would like to set the limits (LCL and UCL) according the tollerances but I do not know how to do.

I write here a simple example to better understand:

```
library(qcc)
data(pistonrings)
diameter <- pistonrings$diameter
q1 <- qcc(diameter, type = "xbar.one", plot = TRUE)
```

This creates the xBar chart defining the two limits according the measurements and confidence interval. I would like to set them as following (just as example) and calculate the results according these values:

```
LCL: 73.99
UCL: 74.02
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It was enough specifying the limits with the qcc function:

```
q1 <- qcc(diameter, type = "xbar.one", plot = TRUE, limits = c(73.99,74.02))
```

Comment: if one only wants to set the lower limit and leave the number limit calculated by QCC, how would that be done?

Comment: I do not know if it is correct, anyhow I did on the following way: q1 <- qcc(diameter, type = "xbar.one", plot = TRUE, limits = c(73.99, NULL))

Comment: I replaced the HCL value with NULL.